# How to use url scheme of iAnnotate in IOS

Tags: ios, pdf

I am creating an iOS App to open a pdf in iAnnotate App, but facing problem in using iAnnotate:// url scheme of the app. Can anybody point the correct usage of the URL scheme to open a pdf in the iAnnotate App from our iPad app.

Answer (score 0):

Branchfire employee here.  Email our support at http://support.branchfire.com/ and include a link to this stackoverflow question so that we know it's you.  That functionality currently does not work, but I've been told that we are currently looking into it.  We'd love to see how you'd like to use our app though and could maybe try to figure something out.